# Imported native function doesn't work in .NET 4.0

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, .net-3.5, pinvoke

I am migrating project from .net 3.5 to .net 4.0 and faced the following issue. 
There are 2 DllImport statements:

```
<DllImport("hid64.dll")> _
Public Sub GenerateHardwareID( _
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex:=1)> ByVal Buffer As Byte(), _
        ByVal BufferLength As Int32)
End Sub

<DllImport("hid64.dll")> _
Public Function BufferToString( _
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex:=1)> ByVal Buffer As Byte(), _
        ByVal BufferLength As Int32) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> String
End Function
```

For the .NET 3.5 both functions work well. But for the .NET 4.0 the call of the BufferToString function breaks execution of the programm without raising any exception.
I played around with CallingConvention, CharSet and so on fields of the DllImport attribute:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx
without success.

This variant:

```
<DllImport("hid64.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, PreserveSig:=False, SetLastError:=True)> _
Public Function BufferToString( _
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)> ByVal Buffer As Byte(), _
        ByVal BufferLength As Int32) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> String
End Function
```

does not break execution of the programm but the function returns 'Nothing'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I believe to be the most likely explanation.

The `BufferToString` function has a return value that is a string. The p/invoke marshaller has to marshal that from native to managed. It does that by assuming that the native code returns a null-terminated character pointer that was allocated by the COM allocator. When it has finished transferring the content to a .net string it calls `CoTaskMemFree` on the pointer. If that memory was not allocated by the COM allocator then you may see failures at this point.

To get around the problem you have a few options. You could change the p/invoke for `BufferToString` to return `IntPtr`. Copy the contents to a .net string with [`Marshal.PtrToStringUni`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dyf0tzy4.aspx). This then leaves you with the responsibility of disposing of the unmanaged memory. Presumably the unmanaged library offers you a mechanism to do that.

If you wrote the unmanaged library then you can use an alternative solution. Leave the p/invoke exactly as it currently is but change the unmanaged library to allocate the return value using `CoTaskMemAlloc`. That then will match with the p/invoke marshaller's assumptions.

Comment: David, thank you very much for clear explanation. It is solution of the issue.